# Colorize stdout output to Windows cmd.exe from console C++ app

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, windows-console

I would like to write something similar to

```
cout << "this text is not colorized\n";
setForeground(Color::Red);
cout << "this text shows as red\n";
setForeground(Color::Blue);
cout << "this text shows as blue\n";
```

for a C++ console program running under Windows 7. I have read that global foreground & background can be changed from cmd.exe's settings, or by calling system() - but is there any way to change things at character-level that can be coded into a program? At first I thought "ANSI sequences", but they seem to be long lost in the Windows arena.

Comment: Use SetConsoleTextAttribute().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleTextAttribute(
  __in  HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  __in  WORD wAttributes
);
```

Here's a brief example which you can take a look.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   HANDLE consolehwnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
   cout << "this text is not colorized\n";
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(consolehwnd, FOREGROUND_RED);
   cout << "this text shows as red\n";
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(consolehwnd, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
   cout << "this text shows as blue\n";
}
```

This function affects text written after the function call. So finally you probably want to restore to the original color/attributes. You can use [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to record the initial color at the very beginning and perform a reset w/ `SetConsoleTextAttribute` at the end.

Comment: Works like a charm. Did not know it was so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to do something minimal-if-possible. This is for code for students to work on, and I would rather keep things real simple.