# How to output colored text in C++ with codeblocks on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, codeblocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Colorize stdout output to Windows cmd.exe from console C++ app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778392/colorize-stdout-output-to-windows-cmd-exe-from-console-c-app)

I am using codeblocks on Windows XP and I need a way to output colored text, and maybe change the color of the background as well in a console application.
I tried the `conio.h` functions but they don't seem to be compatible with code blocks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you change the answer?

Comment: Im kind of noobish.I thought you can accept several answers :D.So then i realised and  i chose the short code.My program already has 4000 code lines(really) and I dont want to add to many of them.And i also want to understand what my codes does.Yours is harder for my to digest, since im not an advanced programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'll want to use some Windows API features to accomplish this.
If you were using Cygwin for windows, it'd be a bit easier.

Here's [an example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/216345) courtesy of daniweb:

```
// color your text in Windows console mode
// colors are 0=black 1=blue 2=green and so on to 15=white
// colorattribute = foreground + background * 16
// to get red text on yellow use 4 + 14*16 = 228
// light red on yellow would be 12 + 14*16 = 236
// a Dev-C++ tested console application by vegaseat 07nov2004

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> // WinApi header

using namespace std; // std::cout, std::cin

int main()
{
    HANDLE hConsole;
    int k;

    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // you can loop k higher to see more color choices
    for(k = 1; k < 255; k++)
    {
        // pick the colorattribute k you want
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, k);
        cout << k << " I want to be nice today!" << endl;
    }

    cin.get(); // wait
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code might help:

WinConsole.h

```
#pragma once

typedef void* HANDLE;

class WinConsole
{
public:
    WinConsole(void);
    ~WinConsole(void);

    void SetColour(WORD colour);

    WORD GetDefaultColour() const;

    void Reset();
private:
    HANDLE fConsoleHandle;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO fDefaultScreenBufferInfo;
};
```

WinConsole.cpp

```
#include "WinConsole.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define <Windows.h>

WinConsole::WinConsole(void)
{
    fConsoleHandle = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != fConsoleHandle)
    {
        ::GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(fConsoleHandle, &fDefaultScreenBufferInfo);
    }
}

WinConsole::~WinConsole(void)
{
}

void WinConsole::SetColour( WORD colour )
{
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != fConsoleHandle)
    {
        ::CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info = { sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO), 0 };
        if(::GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(fConsoleHandle, &info))
        {
            ::SetConsoleTextAttribute(fConsoleHandle, (info.wAttributes & 0xff00)|colour);
        }
    }
}

void WinConsole::Reset()
{
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != fConsoleHandle)
    {
        ::SetConsoleTextAttribute(fConsoleHandle, fDefaultScreenBufferInfo.wAttributes);
    }
}

WORD WinConsole::GetDefaultColour() const
{
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != fConsoleHandle)
    {
        return (WORD)(fDefaultScreenBufferInfo.wAttributes & 0x00ff);
    }
    return e_FGRed | e_FGGreen | e_FGBlue;
}
```

Usage:

```
WinConsole console;
console.SetColour(FOREGROUND_RED|BACKGROUND_BLUE); // Superman style ;)
```

Comment: Thx a lot.You realy worked on this one.